# How to filter by month, day, year with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I create the DataFrame with:

`df = pandas.read_csv("data.csv", sep=';', parse_dates = 1, dayfirst = True)`

I then get the following results:

```
                   Qty     System_created             Total
0                   2  2014-10-14 08:13:46.000         21.76  
1                   1  2014-10-14 08:13:46.000          4.16  
2                   2  2014-10-14 08:30:46.000         27.90  
3                   1  2014-10-14 08:30:46.000          4.95  
4                   1  2014-10-14 08:30:46.000          4.95  
5                   2  2014-11-05 11:15:47.000         21.76  
6                   1  2014-11-05 11:15:48.000          3.32
```

But I do not know how to filter by month(or year, day, hour etc...). Something like `df[df["System_created"].day]` would be ideal. Is that possible?

Comment: From the docs: [.dt accessor](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html#basics-dt-accessors)

Answer (score 11):

So long as your pandas version is `0.15` or higher then the following would work assuming your `dtype` is already a datetime:

```
In [167]:

df[df.System_created.dt.day == 5]
Out[167]:
       Qty      System_created  Total
index                                
5        2 2014-11-05 11:15:47  21.76
6        1 2014-11-05 11:15:48   3.32
```

So basically the `dt` attribute allows you to access the components of your datetime to perform the comparisons you desire for filtering

Comment: What you wrote works. But I want to group by date. With your technique I can only order by a specific day.

Comment: You'll have to explain more, you can certainly specify a specific date to filter or just group by date

Comment: If I do df.groupby(["System_created", "Summen_netto"]).sum() pandas groups it. But pandas groups too detailed. Pandas differentiates between "2014-10-14 08:13:46.000" and "2014-10-14 09:13:46.000". It is the same day but different time of the day. I want pandas to group them together.

Comment: You can do `df.groupby(df.System_created.dt.date).sum()` to groupby the date attribute of the datetime