# creating multiple pandas dataframes based on a list of values and querying using the OR operator

Tags: python, pandas, ipython

I would like to create multiple pandas dataframes by filtering based on values in a list.

if my list (called month) and dataframe (called df) contains [Jan,Feb,Mar]. Here is my code

```
month = df.month.unique().tolist()
for item in month:
    [item] = df[df[month]==[item]]
```

Then if I simply type and run JAN Ipython would show only the january data in tabular form.

**Update -- " KeyError: '2014 Jan' "**

I first thought this was a spacing issue in the columns values, so I replaced them with underscores, but it also doesn't work in columns which only contain a single word and no spaces?

Any Ideas?

Comment: check out this question, which was asked yesterday: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27151546/how-to-filter-by-month-day-year-with-pandas

Comment: When you want to compare multiple conditions you must use `&`, `|`, `~` operators rather than `AND`, `OR` and `NOT` so your query would be something like: `qtr1 = df[(df['month']=="JAN") | (df['month']=="FEB") |(df['month']== "MAR")]` in fact if your month values are in fact strings then the following would work: `qtr1 = df[df['month'].isin(["JAN","FEB","MAR"])]`

Comment: Thanks Paul but I haven't been able to get that to work for creating separate dataframes which are a subset of an original dataset. I'd like to create a separate dataframe for each month of the year where the name of the dataframe is the name of the month, I.e. Jan, Feb, etc. Then I can plot and or manipulate each month separately and look for patterns.